# Three js using merge is slower than not using it

Tags: merge, three.js

If I run the below code that uses merge, then run it without merging, the code runs faster without merge. This is contrary to everything I've read about using merge. Am I doing something wrong?

```
  var width = 800
  var height = 600
  var scene = new THREE.Scene();
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, width / height, 0.1, 1000 );

  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff );
  renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
  renderer.setSize( width, height);
  document.getElementById(self.graphId).appendChild(renderer.domElement)
  var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(10, 24.5, 12);
  var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
  var merged = new THREE.Geometry();

  for ( var i = 0; i < 10000; i ++ ) {

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry);
    mesh.position.x = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
    mesh.position.y = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
    mesh.position.z = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;

    mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
    mesh.updateMatrix();

    //scene.add(mesh);

    merged.merge(mesh.geometry, mesh.matrix);
  }

  var mergedMesh = new THREE.Mesh(merged, material);

  scene.add( mergedMesh);

  renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

Comment: Just to be sure: in your code sample you render only once. We are talking about a slowdown when used in a *render loop*, right? Specifically: merging should in general speed up the rendering, but the merging takes time. The point is you only merge once, at the start.

Comment: @Paul-Jan I'm must taking about the code with the one render. I'm trying to see if it's possible to use webgl to make faster scatter plots. The above code takes about 4 seconds. If I then comment out the merge pieces and uncomment scene.add(mesh), the code takes about 1 second. So this is expected behavior? I'll only see the speedup with multiple renders?

Comment: Exactly. Merging effectively makes the *renderer.render()* call faster, but at a cost that is only offset if you render multiple times (which is the most common usecase for webgl, where you render animations at 60fps). What you should do is time your actual (non-merged) code, and figure out what the slow bits are. Your setup is probably taking up a lot more time than your actual render.